# Rails 4 CSV upload into multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to upload a csv file that has data that belongs in two different models: `Project` and `PurchaseOrder`.  I am using a `has_many, :through` relationship between the models.

I'm having problems with the upload.  I have whitelisted the shared attributes in both controllers and have included the `accepts_nested_attributes` in both models.

Here's my code to read in the csv.

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      project_hash = row.to_hash
      project = Project.where(project_name: project_hash["project_number"]).first
      if project.present?
        project.first.update_attributes(project_hash)
      else
        Project.create! (project_hash)
      end
      purchase_order = PurchaseOrder.where(po_number: project_hash["po_number"]).first
      if purchase_order.present?
        PurchaseOrder.create!
      end
```

I have two questions/problems.

1. I cannot read in the `po_number` attribute.  I get this error `unknown attribute 'po_number' for Project`.
2. I do not know how to push the created purchase order into the project hash so that it updates the nested attribute value.

Thank you in advance to anyone who is able to help!

**** Update
With this method, the data is saved to the correct tables. However, the association between PurchaseOrder and Project is not saved.  Any thoughts?

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      project_hash = row.to_hash
      po_hash = {}
      po = PurchaseOrder.new
      project_hash.each { |k, v| po_hash[k] = project_hash.delete(k) if po.respond_to?(k) }    

      project = Project.where(project_name: project_hash["project_number"]).first
      if project.present?
        project.first.update_attributes(project_hash)
      else
        Project.create! (project_hash)
      end

      po = PurchaseOrder.where(po_number: po_hash["po_number"]).first
      if po.present?
        po.first.update_attributes(po_hash)
      else
        PurchaseOrder.create! (po_hash)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Which line is through the error?  Can you show us?

Comment: I am no longer getting an error.  My new issue is that the association between Purchase Order and Project is not saved.

Comment: Then you have a new question.  A single question should correspond to a single problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are attempting to update / create the project using all the values in the hash...

```
project.first.update_attributes(project_hash)
...
Project.create! (project_hash)
```

But clearly some hash elements (such as "po_number") don't have columns in the projects table.

You need to split out the csv hash elements based on which elements belong to which model...

e.g.

```
po_hash = {}
po = PurchaseOrder.new
project_hash.each { |k, v| po_hash[k] = project_hash.delete(k) if po.respond_to?(k) }
```

This will remove the purchase order fields from `project_hash` and add them to `po_hash` so you can use the correct hash to update the correct table.

To establish the association...

change

```
Project.create!(project_hash)
```

into

```
project = Project.create!(project_hash)
```

so that regardless of whether the project exists or is newly created, it's stored in the variable "project".  Similarly, do

```
po = PurchaseOrder.create!(po_hash)
```

Then after you have created or updated the purchase order, you can simply assign the po to the project...

```
project.purchase_orders << po
```

Comment: Thank you, Steve!  Will this keep the association between project and PO?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I've modified my answer to show a way to do that.